# Sling models explanation

Tags: model, aem, sling

I did a lot of playing around with models... did some really weird things and it was fun.... but now I am bumping in to something which I am not able to wrap my head around. There is the concept of source and there is a concept of via. `@Source` is an annotation which helps me select an injector out of available registered injectors if I want to force one and `@Via` helps me change the default injection behaviour in the context of a given injector. Around these I had the following questions.

1. Whats the difference between `@Source` and `@Via`?

My understanding is `@Source` tells who injects the value and it is always in the context of the adaptables in your `@model` annotation. Certain sources will not work it adaptables is resource and certain ones will not work is the adaptables in `SlingHttpServletRequest`. And within the context of a `@Source @via` tells how the behaviour should be. Here is a weird example but one that works

```
@Inject
@Source("child-resources")
@Named("topnav")
@Via(value = "jcr:content", type = ChildResource.class)
String text;
```

Means inject with injector "child resources", name of the node is "topnav" and within that context, go to the child called `jcr:content` and get the property name called `text`. I know I could have done it much easily with one line but this is just for discussion sake.

Is my understanding correct so far? If yes, are there more examples you can give me?

2. Is the use of injector specific annotations like @ScriptVariable only to reduce the number of lines of code as they look like nothing but two or three basic annotations packed up together.
3. when would I write a custom injector? Is writing a custom injector to pickup request params from a servlet a good scenario?
4. Now the most interesting question. I came across some models which have something like this on the top `@Model` `(adaptables={Resource.class, SlingHttpServletRequest.class}`. I tried doing this never is this treated like a resource. the `SlingHttpServletRequest` is taking precedence as `@Self` never gives me a resource. `@Inject` never gives me the valuemap value. I am forced to add `@Via("resource")` which proves `SlingHttpServletRequest` takes precedence. So it brings me to the question of why this is done? What is the real use or is this just a buggy piece of code?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try answering 2 and 4

2) Yes, they aggregate the standard annotations into one and imply the context better when reading them. Read more here - https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html#custom-injectors-1

4) This is not a behaviour of sling models. You pick an object and then adapt it, so it is always going to be Request or Resource. Which one depends on what object you tried to adapt. You see Request taking precedence because you are likely to be accessing these models via Sightly scripts and the providers that will provide reference to the object specified via the "data-sly-use" attribute prefer request over resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer your questions in the order you asked.

1)  @Source tells the Model to use a specific type of Injector for the Injection, the @Via tells the selected Injector to use a different resource to get the value that will be injected then the base Adaptable. The @Name is used to identify the property, if you use @Name then the property name is ignored. So what is occurring with your example is

`resource.getChild("jcr:content").getValueMap().get("topNav", String.class)

2) Yes, and they are holdovers from the original version of the Sling Models

3) A lot of this depends on the complexity of the model that you are trying to create. Parameters is definitely something that would require a custom Injector although there has been talk in the past about adding that to the current Model injectors. It could be something more complex then what you would be able to do normally, like accessing meta data about a ServletRequest, such as an IP injector.

4) to get the model you take an object that supports the Adaptable interface and you do `apaptableObject.adaptTo(MyModel.class)` The adaptables annotation tells the model what type of objects are acceptable to be used to adapt to this model. The most commonly used are the Resource and SlingHttpServletRequest. So if it's always being treated like a ServletRequest it's because you are using the servletRequest as the object that you are adapting to the model. One of the pain points though is that almost all the injectors work with a request but not all work with a resource. So stating that a model accepts both, means you are limited on what injectors you can use.

Anything that has 'sling' in the package name is part of an open source project and there is a ton of information on their site.

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/models.html